# Can not find -lann and -lcvm

Tags: g++, qmake

I can't figure it out this problem while compiling from qmake `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lann
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcvm`
I have been through a lot of similar questions but still no luck.

I don't have .so library instead got `/home/dhiren/ann_1.1.2/include/ANN/ANN.h` and 
`libGeneralUtils/cvmlib/include/cvm.h`

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Please, add **textual** representation of the error message, not an *image*. Among other reasons, this is a **requirement** of Stack Overflow and noted in [ask].

Comment: It seems you have just downloaded the **sources** of ANN and CVM libraries. You need to **install** those libraries, so you will got corresponded library files. BTW, how is CMake (meaning of `cmake` tag) related to the problem?

Comment: I couldn't find the installable ANN library so I build from source code, at the same way they have provided cvm library inside the source code.